# Why would water flow remain within the soil when seeping through a dam?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

When seeping through a soil dam, water flow is drawn as a curve that start vertically, then goes horizontally, slightly inclined, then following the shape of the toe of the dam.
My question is: what is the intuition of the water not leaving the dam (red lines in the image below) at it seems to me that the atmosphere would offer less resistance than the soil.

[image]

Comment: Cohesion and adhesion.  Water likes to stick to itself and water likes to stick to other things.

Comment: the same reason you've ever had water drip off your elbow